# Schedule Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins

I would like to schedule Jenkins build 9:30 am every morning. How do I set that?

I tried 30 9 * * * but it give me message in yellow flag
Spread load evenly by using ‘H 09 * * *’ rather than ‘30 09 * * *

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The H option is more flexible compare to a fix cron time.

If several jobs are running at the same time on your Jenkins server, you can have a bottleneck regarding your server resources.

Using the H option, Jenkins will improve your jobs schedule and optimise the resources.

But if you want your job to be launched exactly at 9:30am every day, please use 30 9 * * *.

Answer (score 0):

`"30 9 * * *"` is correct if you want the job to run at exactly 9:30am every day.
You can ignore the warning message in this case.

`"H 9 * * *"` will run it sometime between 9:00am and 9:59am every day - this syntax is useful if you want to spread out several jobs over time to avoid overload of resources. E.g. if you have 5 jobs you want run sometime between 9 and 10am, use this syntax.

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering. I got it. I also changed the build time to H(28-30) 9 * * * and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below format

```
H(28-30) 9 * * *
```

Above format will start your Jenkins job around 9:28 AM to 9:30 AM.

The H symbol can be used with a range, To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible.

so that was the reason your are getting warning, but not an error..!